# Unity WebGL - Video Player not looping on older macbook

Tags: unity-game-engine, webgl

In my project, I have a build of Unity WebGL in which I play MP4 videos loaded from a url using Unity's Video Player. These videos are set to loop through the toggle in the inspector. When tested on Safari on my older Macbook, the video gets to the last frame, then freezes. When this happens it takes refreshing the page to get the video to start playing again. On a newer Macbook and on Other devices it works fine.

I've tested on two models of Macbook, a 2014 Air with MacOS 11.6.3 and Safari 14.1.2, and a 2015 Air with MacOS 10.13.5 and Safari 11.1.1

My thoughts are this is caused by the older hardware of the Mac, even with newer versions of the software, but would there be anything else that could be the cause?